# Uk tier 4 student visa has been refused under Paragraph 320(7A) and Paragraph 245ZV(a)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, deception, student-visas

My Uk tier 4 student visa has been refused under Paragraph 320(7A) and Paragraph 245ZV(a).Can I again apply for tier 4 student visa?

Comment: 320(7A) relates to false representations / false documents or information / material facts not disclosed, while 245ZV means the ECO wasn’t satisfied you are a genuine student. On what basis would you reapply?

Comment: Paragraphs only shows general description of what happened, from their point of view. Could you tell us what exactly happened from your point of view? What information or documents might've been considered false? Where were you planning to study, what documents to prove it you had, and why could it look false?